# Multiple rows into json

Tags: postgresql, select, json

Looks my question is unusual because I didn't find the answer at all.
Let's imagine, I have table `A` with columns: `language` and `uri`.

```
language | uri             
---------|-----------------
ru       | some-uri        
en       | some-another-uri
...
```

My question is: How can I return JSON object instead of many rows.
E.g.:

`{
  "ru": "some-uri",
  "en": "some-another-uri",
  ...
}`

Comment: Please tag your DBMS (version included)

Comment: @McNets it is about PostgreSQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's another way that doesn't require type casting: `json_object_agg(name, value)`

```
test=# create table t (name text, value int);
CREATE TABLE
test=# insert into t values ('key1', 1), ('key2', 2), ('key3', 3);
INSERT 0 3
test=# select * from t;
 name | value
------+-------
 key1 |     1
 key2 |     2
 key3 |     3
(3 rows)

test=# select json_object_agg(name, value) from t;
            json_object_agg
----------------------------------------
 { "key1" : 1, "key2" : 2, "key3" : 3 }
(1 row)
```

Comment: You are right, thanks. Since it was posted a couple of years ago, I cannot implement your solution there  but it definitely might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 9):

So, I found out the answer far far away in the documentation.

`SELECT json_object(array_agg(language), array_agg(uri)) FROM A` will give you the expected result.

Comment: You will need to cast the fields (like language and uri) to ::text in case they are not text